# Mobile App Authentication/Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2, basic-authentication

I'm trying to write an app using Sencha Touch that ultimately targets iOS and Android. It's supposed to log into the corporate web server and then retrieve and parse some JSON data. It should be very simple. However I'm very new to both Sencha and Javascript, so I'm having a hard time doing this sort of client-side authentication. I can't even seem to make it authenticate from a web browser on my dev machine.

I used this link to help create my login page:
http://miamicoder.com/2012/adding-a-login-screen-to-a-sencha-touch-application/

But when I attempt to log in I seem to get the following error message and a null object:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.server.com/index.html?=_dc1234567890123
Origin http://localhost:8000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Does anyone have any advice or good resources on getting this app to log in? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Due to some other things I'd read I've been playing with including/excluding the Sencha methods "withCredentials" (set to either True or False, depending on whose suggestions I'm following) and "useDefaultXhrHeader: false", which weren't mentioned in the guide I followed. I'm putting them in the Ext.Ajax.request object in the controller. When I exclude both of those I get this error, which leads me to believe maybe there needs to be something set on the server side?

`OPTIONS https://www.server.com/index.html?=_dc1234567890123 501 (Not Implemented)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steve, the "is not allowed" error is returned because your login request violates the browser's [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) (essentially it states that all XhrHttpRequests must go to the same domain the page was initially loaded from).

Some browsers offer ways of disabling this error temporarily (which might be fine for short-term development purposes), but for the long-term you'll either need to host your application in the same domain as your backend server, or look into using [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) or [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) for your requests.

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX request violates the Same-Origin-Policy. That's why you are getting the error message. If you are using chrome for debugging u can disable the cross-domain Javascript security by doing the following :

For Windows:

> 1) Create a shortcut to Chrome on your desktop.  Right-click on the shortcut and choose Properties, then switch to “Shortcut” tab.
>   2) In the “Target” field, append the following:  –args –disable-web-security

For Mac, Open a terminal window and run this from command-line:

> open ~/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ –args –disable-web-security

For Ubuntu, Open a terminal window and run this form command line:

> open /usr/bin/ and execute ./google-chrome --disable-web-security

Answer (score 0):

There is extension for chrome that does the work:
[‪Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog).
If you want to active it when the browser started, you have to press on the icon.